# TypeScript: Create a new interface without the optional properties

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with optional and required properties, is there a way to use this interface to create a new one which would not have any of the optional properties?

E.g. If we have the following interface:

```
interface FirstInterface {
  name: string,
  surname?: string,
}
```

How can I use it to create a new interface without the optional properties:

```
interface SecondInterface {
  name: string,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
type RequiredKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? never : K }[keyof T]
type RequiredProperties<T> = Pick<T, RequiredKeys<T>>
```

It works by first mapping the interface to a type like `{ name: 'name', surname: never }` in order to extract the names of required keys, and then using `Pick` to pick just the required keys from the original interface.

You can then define `type SecondInterface = RequiredProperties<FirstInterface>`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLCgZzASXNeJZAbwFgAoZZEOAWwgC5lspQBzAGgqswFcoa9APxMW7LuQC+FCmACeABxQAlCAEdeGCABMA0hDmYAPABUAfMgC8JZAG1dyUMgDWBgPYxkJgLoBaEci8INoQMKA6yBAAHpDBmF723shC1BAAbtDITA6Stq5yHl7esooq6ppQOgAKUG5KUGDAEMbmVshVwAjOphzIqhpaegYtZmYy5PJKyADKEAhuwXiQsIgo1v0V1bX1jc1G6Fi4+CtIY+QA9Oc2gozMYKwgbMjS5EA)

Answer (score -2):

You might want to use TypeScript provided [Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

```
type secondInterface = Pick<firstInterface, "name">
// type secondInterface = Omit<firstInterface, "surname"> is equivalent
```

Btw, interfaces should be named in PascalCase